# How to add two videos at a particular point

Tags: c++, python, matlab, image-processing

I have 8 web-cams and I record a lengthy tank with water for ripples. As each webcam can only record a certain portion of the tank, I want to club all the videos of 8 web-cams to give me a perfect video of the ripples in the tank. How can I do it? Any suggestions on languages that would be helpful(C++,matlab for instance). My algorithm is to take a timestamp t=(start to end) and club all the images at every second, but that takes a lot of computation. Is there any other way? Thank you very much.

Comment: How do you expect the final video to look? Does it turn 8 640x480 frames into a single 5120x480 frame? Do the views have overlap? Do you care about the fact that perspective will cause the overlap to depend on distance to camera (thus, since ripples have height, there is no "perfect" algorithm)? It would be much better to process the ripples on individual frames (height, position, speed etc) and then combine this "reduced" data. Can't think of a way to play back the monster video you have in mind. Perhaps you could elaborate a bit?